# Declaration of a custom function in another custom function

Tags: php, function, declare

My 1st function:

```
function db_connect_error_mail ($txt) {
mail(admin_email,mail_subject01,$txt);} //1st three variables come from constants at config.php
```

and 2nd function:

```
function connectdb() {
  $dbc = mysqli_connect (db_host, db_user, db_password, db_name); //variables come from constants at config.php
  if (!$dbc) 
{
$txt = mysqli_connect_errno().mysqli_connect_error();
db_connect_error_mail($txt);
unset ($txt);
die('custom error message to inform viewer');
} else 
    {
        return $dbc;
    }
}
```

**My question:**

Is it okey in index.php just to call connectdb()? If db connection couldn't be set, will I get an email also? (assume that server's mail function works all time)

Comment: Guess, yeah, provided you are including the `config.php` in `index.php`. :)

Comment: @Praveen Kumar: yes I include config.php.

Comment: The answer is 42 (no, you will not get an email since you use `die` - and this stops the execution of your script).

Comment: You won't get an email, as soon as you call die(), the script will stop. Place the die() after the unset('txt);

Comment: thanks, I will place the die() after the unset('txt). Is there any other deficiency?

Comment: I edit my post: placed the die() after the unset('txt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will call <kbd>die</kbd> before <kbd>db_connect_error_mail()</kbd> then no, you won't receive your e-mail as [die()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) function stops execution of any further code.

You might however call your die function **after** sending the error e-mail. this way you will get both: notification mail and an error message.